# Django form template

Tags: django, django-forms

If there were  field.errors  in django, how to to add css class to {{ field }}, example at bottom

```
{% for field in form %}

{{ field }}

{% if field.errors %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Aiming for {{ field }} input type that would have "class=error" when ever there was an error

```
<input class="error">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the class to a wrapper around the field. Django also does this by itself when defining classes in forms.py or views.py

```
{% for field in form %}
<p {% if field.errors %}class="error"{% endif %}
{{ field }}
</p>
{% if field.errors %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately this seems to be the only way. 
Even when Django adds the classes itselt, it prefers to add them to a wrapper of some sort.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#more-granular-output

Scroll down to read about the new thing in 1.2 about adding css classes.
Using this, you can just use form.as_p (or whatever suits you) as the

elements will have all the classes as you define them.
Hope this was a little bit of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use widget_tweaks api to do that.

Instead of rendering a form with

```
{{ form.field }}
```

You should use:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% render_field form.field class="error" %}
```